# Get value from Ruby hash

Tags: ruby

I want to use this Ruby code to get fixed values:

```
FIXED_COUNTRY_TO_PHONE = [
    { country: 'FI', customer_phone: '+4672345678' },
    { country: 'SE', customer_phone: '+4672311178' }
  ].freeze
```

I tries this: `FIXED_COUNTRY_TO_PHONE[country]` but I don't get the customer_phone value. How I can get the value?

Comment: Maybe restructure to `hash = FIXED_COUNTRY_TO_PHONE.map { |h| [h[:country], h[:customer_phone]]  }.to_h #=>  {"FI"=>"+4672345678", "SE"=>"+4672311178"}`. Then you can do
`hash['FI'] #=> "+4672345678"` etc

Comment: I don't want to change the above code. Can you show me how I can get the customer_phone value based on the country code.

Comment: `FIXED_COUNTRY_TO_PHONE.detect { |h| h[:country] == 'FI' }[:customer_phone]`.

Comment: I got `execute': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (RuntimeError)

Comment: There was a typo in the original version of the comment, I have it updated. Try again, it works now.

Comment: In your "try" (`FIXED_COUNTRY_TO_PHONE[country]`), `country` was undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hash is within an array so use this

```
p FIXED_COUNTRY_TO_PHONE.map{|x| x[:country]}
```

output

```
["FI", "SE"]
```

If you want to take the first country then

```
p FIXED_COUNTRY_TO_PHONE.first[:country]
```

If you want to take the last country then

```
p FIXED_COUNTRY_TO_PHONE.last[:country]
```

Getting the country code according to country

```
p FIXED_COUNTRY_TO_PHONE.detect{|x| x[:country].eql?'FI'}[:customer_phone]
```

Comment: I wan to get only FI as output.

Comment: @PeterPenzov Yes, I have updated the code, can you check it?

Comment: One more question how I can get the customer_phone value based on the country code. I want to send the country code and the the fixed value.

Comment: `select {}.first` is called `detect` btw.

Comment: `find` is more idiomatic.

Comment: @SagarPandya why is that?

Comment: @mudasobwa: common sense says so. Wtf is detect? :) I personally only use it on activerecord associations and other things where `find` has another meaning.

Comment: @mudasobwa: also ruby style guide says so, if it has any authority to you :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev you must have known there is no authority to me in ruby at all :) I always use `detect` anyway.

Comment: @mudasobwa: indeed, I knew the answer before I asked. Hence the wording of my comment :)

Comment: So are we agreeing `find` for Ruby, but `detect` for Rails?

Comment: Please don’t count me in this agreement :-P